# Angular get method with new httpClient

Tags: angular, get

is there a equivalent to this "res.json().data" in new HttpClient in angular 5 I'm currently using? Because my api gives me back this kind of json object?

{"data":[{"something":1,"somethingelse":"62968D6B-B50E-4C46-BDB7-8152E3DFB8AC","somethingsomething":null}]}

And previously I've been able to extract data using .data, but no longer can do that, help :(

```
   //in my service
    getUsers() { 
  return this._http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json().data)
       .catch(this._errorHandler);
    }
  //in my component.ts
  this.service.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
   this.users = users;
```

**UPDATE**
In my component

```
       this._usermanagementservice.getEmployees().subscribe((data) => { 
       this.employeelist = data; });
```

And in the service
            getEmployees() {

```
           return this._http.get<employee[]>('url')
           .map(res => res.data)
        }
```

Comment: whats the problem with this? what type of data do you want?

Comment: english is not my primary language so sorry for that, here's the error I get Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

And I've done everything correctly, but can't seem to get my data, data which I use to populate a simple table...

Comment: no problem brother, thats right if you are using ngFor you need array so for that in ngFor use this ngFor="let user of users.something" so something is an array.

Comment: in angular 5 (angular 4.3 I guess,) the httpClient assumes the default response and request format is JSON unless otherwise stated. So you can directly expect an object from HTTP calls without having to parse it on your own. Please accept the below answers if they helped you.

Comment: but my JSON is not classic example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With httpclient, data is automatically converted to an object, and you can explicitely type it

(The typing is not necessary but it's usually easier to use after°

```
interface IUser
{
 name: string;
//other
}

getUsers(): Observable<User[]> { 
  return this._http.get<User[]>(url)
             .catch(this._errorHandler);
    }
```

In your specific example, it looks like the data is in a data property of the response, so you need to use map (like you already do)

```
 getUsers(): Observable<User[]> { 
  return this._http.get(url)
      .map((res : any) => res.data as User[])
       .catch(this._errorHandler);
    }

    //in my component.ts
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(users : User[] => {
this.users = users;
```

Comment: now I get an error saying property data doesn't exist on my type User[]

Comment: angular cli gives me back that error, and my visual studio, but app seems to work just as I want it if I edit my code AFTER "ng serve", crazy lol
now I need to find out if there's something I could do prevent that...

Comment: What error do you get now then? You mention an error about 'User' class, but you don't seem to be using it in the updated code

Comment: yeah, Its' class employee, sorry about that, but back to my previous point, errorI get is that there's no "data" in my class... which is annoying :(

Comment: export class employee {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    address: string;
 
     
}

Comment: Look at the 2nd example in my answer and replace User with employee. You must not type http.get call (it was just to explain the difference in http client). But you can type the map response

Comment: still, res.data won't work, there's no property data on my class :/

Comment: replace res=> with (res: any) =>

Comment: Good bless you brother :)

Comment: You're welcome, I edited the answer to include that missing bit

Answer (score 1):

In new HttpClientModule module we do not need to invoke map() to parse out the response data using the extractData() method. This method has been removed, and we simply return the Observable. The default responseType is JSON, and as such, the response data is already parsed for us.
Try modifying your code to this

In service

```
getUsers() { 
 return this._http.get(url)
}
```

In component

```
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
this.users = users;
```